# Asus Xonar D1 outputs noise after resuming YouTube video playback

Tags: youtube, sound-card

I've bought an Asus Xonar D1 sound card a year ago. Since then I've been enjoying the sound quality and being plagued by it's bugs. Some were solved by switching to 3rd-party drivers, but one bug persisted:

Rarely when putting YouTube video on pause and resuming, the sound-card would output loud white noise. The noise would stop when video is paused again and resumed when resumed (after 1-10 seconds). Meanwhile other sound sources were playing correct. Restarting the video (with F5) did not help. Playing other YouTube videos would produce same noise too (iirc). As if YouTube videos were getting cursed.

The bug persisted with official and 3rd-party drivers. Which lead me to believe that's a software problem somewhere around firmware or drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remedy:

Leave all videos paused for around 20 seconds, then resume. Suddenly the sound is fixed.